# Merged 2 List into Dictionary without losing any Element in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5

I have 2 list with the length value of 35 in total both listA and listB. However when I merged the 2 list one of the element is gone and the length become lesser becomes 33. is there any way to make 2 list into a dict without losing any element? I tried the zip and normal for loop but still I lost something.

```
listA = ['Produkttyp', 'Integrerade komponenter', 'Spårningsdata', 'Bärstil', 'Urtavla', 'Satta mål', 'Funktioner', 'EAN', 'MPN', 'Typ', 'Upplösning', 'Mått (BxH)', 'Trådlöst gränssnitt', 'Typ', 'Batteritid', 'Information om boetten', 'Namn', 'Storlek', 'Fits Wrist with Circumference', 'Låstyp', 'Material', 'Färg', 'Bredd', 'Djup', 'Längd', 'Vikt', 'Förinstallerad programvara', 'Vibrerande alarm', 'Material', 'Skydd', 'Inkluderade tillbehör', 'Emballagets bredd', 'Emballagets djup', 'Emballagets höjd', 'Emballagets vikt']

listB = ['Aktivitetspårare', 'Hjärtfrekvenssensor', 'Distans, tid, brända kalorier, aktivitet, sovaktivitet, hjärtfrekvens, steg tagna, Antal våningar upp, stressnivå, styrka', 'Handled', 'Ja', 'Ja', 'Meddelande om missade samtal, musikfjärrhantering, SMS-meddelande, E-postmeddelande, kamerafjärrkontroll, Bluetooth Smart-teknologi, automatisk övningsigenkänning, notiser via sociala media, Move IQ, accelerometer, miljöljussensor, barometer, hjärtfrekvens, VO2 max', '753759205157', '010-01995-03', 'OLED - monokrom', '128 x 48 pixlar', '6.6 mm x 17.7 mm', 'Bluetooth 4.0, ANT+', 'Pekskärm', '7 dag(ar)', 'Midnattssvart', 'Band', 'L', '148-215 mm', 'Spänne', 'Silikon', 'Svart', '15 mm', '10.5 mm', '223 mm', '21.5 g', 'VO2 Max, Fitness Age, Move IQ', 'Ja', 'Aluminium', 'Vattentät', 'Laddnings-/datakabel', '14.1 cm', '6.9 cm', '6.2 cm', '116.2 g']
```

dict(zip(listA, listB))

```
the result will be: 33 only 
'Produkttyp':'Aktivitetspårare'
'Integrerade komponenter':'Hjärtfrekvenssensor'
'Spårningsdata':'Distans, tid, brända kalorier, aktivitet, sovaktivitet, hjärtfrekvens, steg tagna, Antal våningar upp, stressnivå, styrka'
'Bärstil':'Handled'
'Urtavla':'Ja'
'Satta mål':'Ja'
'Funktioner':'Meddelande om missade samtal, musikfjärrhantering, SMS-meddelande, E-postmeddelande, kamerafjärrkontroll, Bluetooth Smart-teknologi, automatisk övningsigenkänning, notiser via sociala media, Move IQ, accelerometer, miljöljussensor, barometer, hjärtfrekvens, VO2 max'
'EAN':'753759205157'
'MPN':'010-01995-03'
'Typ':'Pekskärm'
'Upplösning':'128 x 48 pixlar'
'Mått (BxH)':'6.6 mm x 17.7 mm'
'Trådlöst gränssnitt':'Bluetooth 4.0, ANT+'
'Batteritid':'7 dag(ar)'
'Information om boetten':'Midnattssvart'
'Namn':'Band'
'Storlek':'L'
'Fits Wrist with Circumference':'148-215 mm'
'Låstyp':'Spänne'
'Material':'Aluminium'
'Färg':'Svart'
'Bredd':'15 mm'
'Djup':'10.5 mm'
'Längd':'223 mm'
'Vikt':'21.5 g'
'Förinstallerad programvara':'VO2 Max, Fitness Age, Move IQ'
'Vibrerande alarm':'Ja'
'Skydd':'Vattentät'
'Inkluderade tillbehör':'Laddnings-/datakabel'
'Emballagets bredd':'14.1 cm'
'Emballagets djup':'6.9 cm'
'Emballagets höjd':'6.2 cm'
'Emballagets vikt':'116.2 g'
len():33
```

Comment: if there were repeating keys in your dictionary then they would be overwritten by the most recent one thus explaining the less no of keys.

Comment: There are two `'Typ'` in the first list, so since a dictionary has unique keys, the first gets overwritten by the second. This code is working as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

listA contains two duplicated items ('Material' and 'Typ'). Dictionaries cannot have duplicated keys which explains why you are seeing less entries in your dict.

If you have duplicated keys, the best approach would be to make the value of the dictionary a list instead of a single item created as follows:

The dictionary then has 33 keys but 35 values as the entries for 'Typ' and 'Material' contain 2 items in the list.

```
d = dict()

for key, val in zip(listA, listB):
    if key in d:
        d[key].append(val)
    else:
        d[key] = [val]
```

If we then look at the entry for 'Typ' we see:

```
d['Typ']
['OLED - monokrom', 'Pekskärm']
```